# Remove app notification when app opens from launcher

Tags: notifications, stock-android, launcher

I have looked all over the place and cannot seem to find a way to automatically remove an app's respective notification upon the app opening from the app launcher. In iOS this behavior was just a given but, in Android the notifications remain even after opening the app.  If I open the app from the notification, the notification is cleared out, but I may not want to open the app from the notification because it may take me to a part of the app that I don't want to go to (like directly into a particular email rather than the inbox).

I am on a Note 9 running 8.1.0.  Not rooted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From searching, an app developer can [program this functionality in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249851/remove-notification-icon-when-user-open-app-through-launcher-icon) but I don't think there's a global setting for it. You can investigate into IFTTT type apps like [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_AU) or [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate) - shouldn't be too difficult to set up a trigger when an app is in foreground and then clear notifications (or disable then enable it if clearing is not supported).